# Select first three li elements of each individual list to each specific p tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, function

So basically to make it easy to explain, this HTML code below is what I am looking to achieve through using JavaScript, I do not want to use jQuery for this.

```
<div class="list-desc">
    <h6>
        First List
        <p class="label" id="filt-copy">
            Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
        </p>
    </h6>
    <ol id="list">
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 1</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 2</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 3</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>
                <span>Item 4</span>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="list-desc">
    <h6>
        Second List
        <p class="label" id="filt-copy">
            Item 5, Item 6, Item 7
        </p>
    </h6>
    <ol id="list">
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 5</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 6</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 7</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>
                <span>Item 8</span>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

This is what the original version looked like below.

```
<div class="list-desc">
    <h6>
        First List
        <p class="label" id="filt-copy">
            Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 5, Item 6, Item 7
        </p>
    </h6>
    <ol id="list">
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 1</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 2</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 3</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>
                <span>Item 4</span>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="list-desc">
    <h6>
        Second List
        <p class="label" id="filt-copy">
            Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 5, Item 6, Item 7
        </p>
    </h6>
    <ol id="list">
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 5</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 6</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="list-item">
                <span>Item 7</span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>
                <span>Item 8</span>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I am hoping to achieve this above through the use of JavaScript, at the minute I have only managed to show all of the list items rather than just the first three of each individual list. My code I have attempted so far is shown below. Does anybody know how I can achieve this or where I have gone wrong in my code shown below?

```
const list = () => {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.list-desc ol > li:not(:nth-child(n + 4))');
    const label = document.querySelectorAll('p.label');

    const appendItems = () => {
        items.forEach(el => {
            el.classList.add('list-item');
            const clone = el.cloneNode(true);

            for (i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
                label[i].id = "filt-copy";
                label[i].append(clone.innerText);
            }

        });
    };
    appendItems();
});

list();
```

Any help would be seriously appreciated.

Comment: Probably should show what the initial HTML looks like and then put the whole thing in a snippet (well, leave the desired result as formatted code in your question, but the rest in a snippet)

Comment: @Kinglish thankyou for replying, I've updated my question above to include the initial HTML and my desired version :)